# What does it mean to say a RV is fully defined by its distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

I get that a CDF is used to observe the behaviour of a distribution and therefore the corresponding RV ? But what does it mean to fully defined by its distribution and what does this have to do with random processes ?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, where $\Omega$ is just some set (your outcomes), $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$ (if you haven't used it yet, just ignore this part) and $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure, and you have a real-valued random variable $X$. The distribution of $X$ is defined as $\mathbb{P}_X(A) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A)$, where $A$ is a reasonable set (e.g. a Borel set, or just any set of the form $\{ x : x \le a \}$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, depending on your knowledge). $\mathbb{P_X}$ itself is described by two quantities a priori: the measure $\mathbb{P}$ and the random variable $X$. If you have another probability space $(\Omega_2, \mathbb{P}_2)$ and a RV $X_2$ such that whatever reasonable set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ you take, you always have $\mathbb{P}(X \in A) = \mathbb{P}_2(X_2 \in A)$, then $X$ and $X_2$ are said to be equally distributed (i.e. the experiment might look different, but if you just observe $X$ and $X_2$, from the viewpoint of probability theory you will be unable to differ between these two experiments).

Additionally you should know that a cumulative distribution function describes a measure uniquely, i.e. if you have two different measures $\mu_1, \mu_2$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the corresponding c.d.f. $F_1, F_2$ agree for all points, then the measures itself agree. Note that this is nontrivial, since $F(x)$ just gives you the probability of sets as $(-\infty, x]$, whereas the measure $\mu_1$ gives probabilities to more complex sets. So whenever you have two distributions that are equal in the sense of the first paragraph, you will always have $F_1 = F_2$.

I would not give a link to stochastic processes, but it is rather a property of a single random variable (or two random variables if you like). Processes are just collections of random variables, so most concepts can be generalized to processes.

Hope this helps. If you have any questions, don't hesitate to comment.